# How to filter observations in pandas data frame using a for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, subset

I have a pandas data frame with three columns I'm interested in (City, Country, and Sports Team). I want to filter it where Country = Italy and Sports Team = Soccer then print out the cities that meet that criteria. It must be done in a for loop...

I have tried:

```
for i,a in mydf.iterrows():
    if mydf['Country'][i] == "Italy":
    if mydf['Sports Team'][a] == "Soccer":
    Print('City')
```

It says: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code writing service. Please provide some sample input and desired output along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    mydf[(mydf['Country'] == 'Italy')&(mydf['Sports Team'] == 'Soccer')]['City']
```

That should give you a DataFrame column of cities that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of filtering a pandas dataframe, but since you are using `iterrows()`, I have answered using that,

```
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
my_data = [{
            'Country': 'Italy',
            'City': 'City 1',
            'Sports Team': 'Soccer'
        },
        {
            'Country': 'Italy',
            'City': 'City 2',
            'Sports Team': 'Soccer'
        }]

mydf = pd.DataFrame(my_data)

for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
    if row['Country'] == 'Italy' and row['Sports Team'] == 'Soccer':
        print(row['City'])
```

`mydf` looks like,

```
   City     Country    Sports Team
0  City 1   Italy      Soccer
1  City 2   Italy      Soccer
```

and the output will be,

```
City 1
City 2
```

Answer (score 0):

try..

It's better using .loc and .iloc

### DataFrame Example:

```
>>> mydf
     City Country Sports Team
0  City 1   Italy      Soccer
1  City 2   Italy      Soccer
2  City 3   Spain      Soccer
3  City 4  Brazil    Football
4  City 2   Italy    Football
```

### Result:

```
>>> mydf.loc[(mydf['Country'] == 'Italy') &  (mydf['Sports Team'] == 'Soccer')]['City']
0    City 1
1    City 2
Name: City, dtype: object
```